# How to get all objects of a class in Realm to an array

Tags: swift, realm

Currently I am using this:

```
    var matchedUsersFromRealm = MatchedUser.allObjects()
    var matchedUsersInRealm = RLMArray(objectClassName: MatchedUser.className())
    matchedUsersInRealm.removeAllObjects()
    matchedUsersInRealm.addObjects(matchedUsersFromRealm)
```

But it just looks cumbersome rather than just getting it in one line as it should (or did?). Maybe there is a better way?

PS, I am working on a mix project and somehow I can only use the Objective-C version and bridge it to my swift project. So the Realm().objects() is not available, even though it returns a Results not an array.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add these extensions:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

extension Results {

    func toArray() -> [T] {
        return self.map{$0}
    }
}

extension RealmSwift.List {

    func toArray() -> [T] {
        return self.map{$0}
    }
}
```

And then when fetching:

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    let objs = realm.objects(MyObjType).toArray() 
    // ...

} catch _ {
    // ...
}
```

(Remove do try catch if you're using Swift pre-2.0)

Note that this loads everything into memory at once, which may be in some cases not desired. If you're fetching in the background, it's required though, as Realm currently doesn't support using the objects in the main thread after that (you will also have to map the array to non-Realm objects in this case).

Comment: Thanks! I am quite new to Realm so I am still thinking the old way of using arrays and keep it loaded for uses such as datasource of a tableview. segiddins mentioned the performance tradeoff, I am curious what is the most efficient way with Realm for these cases.

Comment: Well, if you load the Realm objects in the main thread the `toArray()` could block the UI, and in that case it's also not necessary to map to not-Realm objects, so I think it makes sense that you use the Realm objects directly as data source. This is only if for some reason you want to do the fetch in the background or prefer having a model object layer to decouple from the database...

Comment: That said, I haven't tested myself and could imagine that since the realm objects load lazily, the performance accessing them would be worser than if you pre-load the model objects in memory using `toArray`. It could be that the tableview scrolls smoother with the pre-loaded array.

Comment: I wrote this post with some utility functions to work with Realm: http://randomprogrammingthings.blogspot.de/2015/07/some-utility-functions-to-work-with.html you may take a look into that (just for the "how to" - it doesn't have any performance tests).

Comment: Yes, the performance issue had me thinking. Your help function collections looks great. They are in Swift and I am not sure if it can be used to extend the ObjectiveC version of Realm. It still feels annoying to me that I have to use the ObjectiveC version because I have other pods using a bridging header.

Comment: So far my experience having a bridging header doesn't hinder you from using Swift libraries.

Answer (score 8):

I preferred to add a helper class to save and retrieve any type of objects using Generics.

```
class RealmHelper {
    static func saveObject<T:Object>(object: T) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(object)
        }
    }
    static func getObjects<T:Object>()->[T] {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let realmResults = realm.objects(T.self)
        return Array(realmResults)

    }
    static func getObjects<T:Object>(filter:String)->[T] {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let realmResults = realm.objects(T.self).filter(filter)
        return Array(realmResults)

    }
}
```

Comment: tell also how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all objects of User in 1 line :

```
let matchedUsers = Realm().objects(MatchedUser)
```

Comment: This gives you a RLMResults rather than a RLMArray. I want an array. PS, I am working on a mix project and somehow I can only use the Objective-C version and bridged to my swift project.

Answer (score 1):

`RLMArray`s are meant to represent to-many relationships. `RLMResults` are meant to represent the result of a database query. If, however, you're looking to get a plain old Swift array (and are OK with performance tradeoffs of using that versus an `RLMResults`), you can do `map(MatchedUser.allObjects()) { $0 }`

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful explanation. Can you please elaborate on the tradeoff? I am using array right now because I want to load it and do operations on it without read from Realm every time. If using RLMResults is the better way to go, I am happy to switch.

Comment: `RLMResults` is lazy-loaded, so it has a much lower memory footprint, and won't cause every object to be immediately loaded into memory. Reads from Realm are practically instantaneous, so lazy-loading the objects is almost always a performance win.

Comment: So when it comes to use it as datasource for tableview, which is better? To preload in an array, or lazy-loading at each cell?

Comment: In my opinion, it's almost always better just to use the `RLMResults`.

Answer (score 0):

Because RLMResults is a lazy loading array. So if you want to return an array, just write an extension for Results.
Example:

```
extension Result {
  func toArray() -> [T] {
    let newArray: [T] = []
    // At here you should append the value from self into newArray
    ...
    return newArray
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
let array = Array(realmResult)
```